# MVC 5 Entity Framework 6 Duplicating Records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am having a strange problem using Entity Framework 6 Model First in ASP.Net MVC 5.

I have class of student and a class of family. A family can have many students.

I can add a family without problems, but when I add a student for that family it make two records with different keys.

This are my models:

```
     public partial class Family
{
    public Family()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        this.Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
    }

    public System.Guid FamilyId { get; set; }
    public string PayerType { get; set; }
    public bool ProblemAccount { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string CustomId { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

   public partial class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.Phones = new HashSet<Phone>();
        this.Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
        this.Classes = new HashSet<Class>();
    }

    public System.Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public System.Guid FamilyFamilyId { get; set; }
    public string CustomId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool MassEmail { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Transportation { get; set; }
    public string School { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public bool Citizenship { get; set; }

    public virtual Family Family { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller to add a student:

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> AddNewStudent(Guid FamilyId, NewRegistrationViewModel model)
    {

        model.Student.StudentId = Guid.NewGuid();
        model.Student.FamilyFamilyId = FamilyId;
        db.Students.Add(model.Student);

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return View();
    }
```

The only way I made it not to duplicate was by not generating a new guid for StudentId.
If i comment the first line of my AddNewStudent Controller it will save ok but without guid and off course we dont want that.

Like this:

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> AddNewStudent(Guid FamilyId, NewRegistrationViewModel model)
    {

        //model.Student.StudentId = Guid.NewGuid();
        model.Student.FamilyFamilyId = FamilyId;
        db.Students.Add(model.Student);

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some type of database mapping using [Configuring/Mapping Properties and Types with the Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx) or [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx).

**Data Annotations** would look something like this.

```
[Table("Family")
public partial class Family
{
[Key]
public System.Guid FamilyId { get; set; }
---
```

**Fluent Mapping** looks like this and goes in **OnModelCreating** (probably in  YourDbContext.cs)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Family>().HasKey(t => t.FamilyId);
```

Comment: That is if it was Code First but that model was generated by Model First.